# What to do with Perforce if port 1666 is blocked by ISP?

Tags: networking, server, network-programming, port, perforce

So I've set up a Perforce server on a Google Cloud VM Ubuntu denial, and I'm pretty sure by now nothing is wrong with it, I checked if it is listening to the port 1666, and set a firewall exception for it on the cloud.

But on the other hand, I've been bashing my head for 3 days trying to connect my client Perforce from my Windows 10 to the server and the connection keeps timing out with this message

> Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
>
> connect: 104.199.67.175:1666: WSAETIMEDOUT

So then I checked if my ISP is blocking this port via http://canyouseeme.org/ and I found out that not only is 1666 blocked, but all other ports I've tried were not working as well (80, 8080, 22, 43, ...etc) and I have no idea how that's possible.
Can anyone please explain what exactly this means(all ports blocked) and if there is a way around it to set up the server on a different port or something like that (maybe make Perforce client go through a proxy or VPN service?)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The Helix Server can be started on any port, provided another service is not already using it, just specify it when starting the server.

Example:
  p4d -r  -p 1888

Regarding the issue with your client machine, I suggest you check that the Windows Firewall is not blocking the ports.

Hope that helps,
Jen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
So, I know I can change the helix server's port but it doesn't help as long as the client machine can't access any port.
I have checked Windows Firewall and made an exception rule for port 1666, and still it's not working, that's why I figured it's from the ISP.